# Using ".init_array" section of ELF file

Tags: linux, assembly, elf, gnu-assembler

When there is a need to run a piece of code on the program startup (on Linux), how to use correctly the `.init_section` of an executable file (ELF32-i386)? I have the following code (GNU Assembler) which has `ctor` initialization function, and the address of this function is placed inside `.init_array` section:

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
.data
s1: .asciz "Init code\n"
s2: .asciz "Main code\n"
.global _start
.global ctor
.text
ctor:
    mov     eax, 4           # sys_write()
    mov     ebx, 1           # stdout
    mov     ecx, offset s1 
    mov     edx, 10
    int     0x80
    ret

.section .init_array
    .long ctor

.text
_start:
    mov     eax, 4
    mov     ebx, 1
    mov     ecx, offset s2
    mov     edx, 10
    int     0x80

    mov     eax, 1
    mov     ebx, 0
    int     0x80
```

This code is assembled with:

```
as -o init.o init.asm
ld -o init init.o
```

When the resulting executable is run, only the "Main code" string is printed. How to use properly the .init_array section?

EDIT1: I want to use .init_array because there are multiple source files with their own init code. One can call all this code 'manually' on startup and modify it every time when source files are added to or removed from the project, but `.init_array` seems to be designed just for this case :

> Before transferring control to an application, the runtime linker
>   processes any initialization sections found in the application and any
>   loaded dependencies. The initialization sections .preinit_array,
>   .init_array, and .init are created by the link-editor when a dynamic
>   object is built.
>
> The runtime linker executes functions whose addresses are contained in
>   the .preinit_array and .init_array sections. These functions are
>   executed in the same order in which their addresses appear in the
>   array.

In case when an executable is created without gcc, the linker seems to not execute the startup code. I tried to write my own standard init routine which reads function pointers in .init_array, section and calls them. It works OK for one file, where one can mark the end of the section, for example, with zero. But with multiple files this zero can be relocated in the middle of the section. How can one correctly determine the size of a section assembled from multiple source files?

Comment: The gnu ld default linker script does provide symbols `__init_array_start` and `__init_array_end` on some systems automatically, so you might be able to use those. YMMV.

Comment: @Jester, thanks, that could be the accepted answer.

Comment: https://maskray.me/blog/2021-11-07-init-ctors-init-array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you make a **statically linked** bare executable the way you're doing, with your own code at the `_start` entry point, your code just runs from that point.  If you want something to happen, your code has to make it happen.  There is no magic.

Using sections can be useful to group startup code from multiple source files together, so all the startup code is cold and can potentially be paged out, or at least not need a TLB entry.

So you "properly use" sections by putting functions there and calling them from code that runs sometime after `_start`.

In your code example, it looks like `.init_array` is a list of function pointers.  I assume the standard CRT startup files read the ELF file and find the length of that section, then walk through it making indirect calls to those functions.  Since you're making custom code, it's going to be faster just to call an init function that does everything.

---

#### dynamic linking:

The "runtime linker" is the ELF interpreter for dynamic binaries.  It runs code in your process before `_start`, so yes, apparently it does process that ELF section and make magic happen.

---

So in response to your edit, your options are: implement this processing of `.init_array` yourself, or create dynamic executables.  I'm pretty sure this procedure has been covered in other questions, and I don't have time to research a correct command line for a dynamic executable that still doesn't link libc.  (Although you might just want to use `gcc -nostartfiles`, or something.)

If you're stuck, leave a comment.  I may update this later when I have more time anyway, or feel free to edit in a working command.

Comment: @AlBerger: that's a better place for more info anyway.  Interesting, I didn't know the exact mechanism for having constructors run.  Updated my answer.

Comment: I implemented the starting mechanism which reads function pointers from .init_array, but only when there is a single source file with .init_array section. When there are multiple files, the problem is how to determine the .init_array section size (how to know how many function pointers in the section). Maybe there is a standard and simple method, but I don't know it (I'm a newbie in Assembler.).

Comment: @AlBerger: So you don't want to make a dynamic executable?  I think you'd want to read the ELF headers yourself do that.  Note that when your executable is mapped into memory, with `_start` at whatever address, the bytes of the file before that are right there in memory, at least within that page.  I'm not sure if it's a good idea to depend on that or not.  But for a custom solution, you might just put a sentinel value (`0`) as the last element.  In your build script / Makefile, make sure the file with the NULL entry is linked last.  Then you don't need startup code that reads ELF headers.

Comment: Unfortunately, the sentinel in the last file introduces an additional dependency to control and keep in mind. If there is no an API-like or some other straightforward method to determine section sizes, I think I will use some kind of internal counter, which is incremented in files which add function pointers to .init_array.

Comment: As for dynamical linking, I also have tried it: linking with "-lc -e main -I/lib/ld-linux.so.2", but startup code hasn't been called. I guess one has to link with gcc in order to get automatic execution of startup code.

Comment: @AlBerger: hmm, the wording implies it's the `ld.so` dynamic linker that does it, not the CRT start files, but perhaps that doc is wrong.  re: parsing ELF files: The `elf(5)` man page documents `Elf32_Shdr` (defined in `elf.h`, which indicates that every ELF section header includes the length of the section.  To see how it's "supposed to be done", I'd make a C++ program with some dynamically initialized global variables, and then single-step (or set a watchpoint on them to break when they're written).  Backtrace to see how you got there.

Comment: I guess I'd be inclined to roll my own ABI for initialization.  Maybe just include code that initializes stuff and then falls through to the next chunk of code.  Then either the next ELF section, or the end of that ELF section, could hold a `ret` instruction.  `_start` would just call that init function which is pieced together by the linker.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I think that reading the elf image and basic parsing to get the section length will do.

Answer (score 1):

For normal C programs the `.init_array` is traversed by a function that is called from `_start` before main gets called. A good description is on [this](http://www.dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/debugging/linuxProgramStartup.html) site.

So I see two ways: You can simply link against the glibc start code. Or you have to find out another mechanism to solve this issue by yourself.